# grails charts with sparklines/zingchart

Tags: grails, charts, sparklines

I'm looking to make a bar graph for my webapp that takes data from a mySQL server. I want to use either sparklines or zinchart for my webapp. I've already tried to use them myself but I keep getting stuck. For sparklines I am using this in inside my body tads:

```
<sparklines:bar id="id" values="threads" />
```

where id is the id of my table and threads is the column with the relevant data. ID would be on the x axis and threads on the y. The sparkline code above compiled and seemed to work, except that where my graph was supposed to be there was just one word "Loading..."

As for zingapp I used the example in the plugin page:

```
<zing:chart type="area" width="700" height="350" 
container="acceptToConvertChart" data="${data}" xLabels="${labels}" effect="4" />
```

but just changed data to dbContent, which is mapped from my controller to my view like so:

```
        def appProjects = Threadcount.list()
    [dbContent: appProjects]
```

and for "labels" I used dbContent.id. When I ran the zingChart code I got the following error:

> No signature of method:
>   zingchart.ZingChartTagLib$_closure2_closure3.doCall() is applicable
>   for argument types: (threadsapp.Threadcount) values:
>   [threadsapp.Threadcount : 1] Possible solutions:
>   doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(),
>   call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object),
>   call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll()

it also says that the line: container="acceptToConvertChart" data="${data}" xLabels="${labels}" effect="4"/> 
is the culprit.

Does anyone know the proper syntax to make either of the two code snipets work? Or if you have had the same problem or something very similar, how did you fix it?